# Acer Swift SF314-57G fan speed control

Tags: windows-10, laptop, fan, cooling

I am currently using an Acer Swift SF314-57G laptop with the latest Windows 10 operating system. According to my understanding, Acer have their own SmartFan cooling system, but it does not seem to be very efficient. When I am charging my laptop, it can heat up to 70°C but the fan is barely at half power. I am worried that my laptop will overheat and hence would like to inquire if there is any solution to take control of the fan speed of my laptop. I have searched many forums but none of the solutions seem to work. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried changing the 'system cooling policy' in your 'advanced power plan' settings?

Comment: Yes I have set it to active for both plugged in and on battery, but it does not not seem to work

Comment: Try using third party software, such as speedfan, etc. Look some up on Google, there are many good choices, and see if you can do anything with them.

Comment: Yes I have tried numerous software but they do not work as they could not detect my fan. If I remembered correctly, Acer seem to have controlled our ability to access the fan, such that I could not access the fan setting in BIOS. Is there anyway to get by these restriction? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, no there isn't, as your motherboard is pre-built, and the BIOS is very restrictive.

Comment: Hmm, then is it possible to recommend an app that can work for Acer? Thanks.

Comment: I've heard NoteBook FanControl works for Acer users. Kindly try this and report back.

Comment: It does not have any support for my acer laptop model